# Handling Pinch Zoom Gestures

Tags: iphone, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am working with the apple sample code _TapToZoom. They handled single, double taps using UIGestureRecognizers to scale the scrollview(with image) when user taps. Now I would like to implement the same functionality when user pinch zooming on the image scrollview. I am going through the so many links, but not helpful. Please help me to resolve this....

Answer (score 1):

Add the gesture recognizer like so:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(<your gesture handling callback>:)]; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
[pinch release];
```

This condition will check if the gesture recognizer is a UIPinhcgestureRecognizer and the inner conditions check if the user has pinched or zoomed:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [gesture setString:kPinchGesture];
        if (((UIGestureRecognizer*)sender).state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            if (((UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender).scale < 1) {
                NSLog(@"Pinched");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Zoomed");
            }

        }
```